# jquery Range slider with one knob

Tags: jquery, slider, rangeslider

Please have a look on this [Demo](http://developer.expressionz.in/downloads/mootools_double_pinned_slider_with_clipped_gutter_image_v2.2/slider_using_mootols_1.2.html)

Have a look on "Mootols Slider with one knob" section. I want to implement this slider. But instead of using Min and Max, I want to use fixed values or we can say values in array.e.g., slider should move for {6,12,18,24,48} these valuse only. Any help on this will be appreciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, there's a jQuery UI plugin called "slider" and it can do exactly what you'd like: [snap to increments](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps)

Comment: Ya that is fine. But the example that you are showing is for fixed incremental values. But I am looking for non-linear values e.g., {13,18,27,56,100}